# Create a loop for read a text file or real time changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, what I did it's to collect an information from a text file, and then transform that into text on the html page. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="text" class="text"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var text_print = new XMLHttpRequest();
        text_print.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
        text_print.onload = function (){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=text_print.responseText;
        text_print.send(null);
```

What I need to do now, it's to make this script run every second.
The `file.txt` in my server changes constantly, so I need that the information printed on screen change when the file changes.
Thank you.

Comment: every second.... I doubt your server will enjoy that

Comment: Don't do this. This is not secure and wastes bandwidth. Use a [socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) instead.

Comment: Hi epascarello and Derek. First, thanks for your advices! As I mentioned in the comment for willicab, this project is local only, using a local server. It won't go be upload and become public website. This really could cause problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient way to do it, but if you still decide to continue, this can help you.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    var text_print = new XMLHttpRequest();
    text_print.open("GET", "http://localhost/post/file.txt", true);
    text_print.send();
    text_print.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (text_print.readyState == 4) {
            if(text_print.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=text_print.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi, willicab! First of all, thanks for your awnser, did work great, just as I needed. But since the members are saying it's not good for the server, I'm kinda concerned. My project actually is local, I don't know how did you know that, since you put a URL for local hosted file (coincidence maybe?), but the text file only has 1 line. When it changes, change only that line, staying with one line. So, the files are not big, since it's a text file with one line. This could really cause problems? Even been small files? Again, it's only local and I'm NOT going to upload this for public web. Thx.

Comment: Well, there should be more problem, but as always as more clients make calls more work will have the server, you could do a stress test to verify that